# I have problem in data return from webhooks not json data

Tags: c#, php, json, .net, webhooks

I got this data returned from webhooks, but it's not a JSON object and can't use it currently. What kind of object is this and how can I Serialize this with C# or PHP?

```
{{
  "data": "{\"event\":\"INBOX\",\"from\":\"966******\",\"to\":\"966******\",\"text\":\"https:\\/\\/fs.magicrepository.com\\/incoming\\/4ef5613331213ab08888fb7cf72f332c.jpg\",\"alias\":\"\",\"pushname\":\"\",\"profilepicture\":\"\"}"
}}
```

Comment: That's still JSON

Comment: Well, other than the double-braces, it's double-encoded

Comment: Do you want to serialize or deserialize this data? Since you said that received this data, I assume you mean you want to deserialize the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Convert the data from webhook in json decoded form and then save it.

```
$decoded_data = json_decode($data, true);
```

For the slashes issue

```
$decoded_data = json_decode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

(Edited)

Comment: The data as shown _is not_ valid JSON, so trying to use json_decode on it is rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to deserialize the input:

1. trim the excess curly braces
2. Decode the result as JSON
3. Decode the value of the `data` property as JSON.

INn C#, it would look like this:

```
using System.Text.Json;


/* assuming input is like:
 * {{ 
 *  "data": "{\"event\":\"INBOX\",\"from\":\"966******\",\"to\":\"966******\",\"text\":\"https:\\/\\/fs.magicrepository.com\\/incoming\\/4ef5613331213ab08888fb7cf72f332c.jpg\",\"alias\":\"\",\"pushname\":\"\",\"profilepicture\":\"\"}"
 * }}
 */
var unwrapped = input[1..(input.Length - 1)];
var outerDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(unwrapped).RootElement;
var innerDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(outerDoc.GetProperty("data").GetString()).RootElement;
```